# Azure DSC Extension. HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\PowerShell\3\DSC doesn't exist

Tags: azure, azure-powershell, dsc, azure-rm-template

I'm trying to create an Azure RM Template with SQL Server 2016 AlwaysOn Avaiability Group by using this base template http://4c74356b41.com/post5775
The template I linked is too complex for me. I just need to create 2 VMs and 1 Storage Account and apply proper DSC to the VMs. I'm getting the following error while applying configuration sql-primary and configuration sql-secondary to the both VMs:

```
Cannot find path 'HKLM:\\SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\PowerShell\\3\\DSC' because it does not exist. 
A duplicate resource identifier '[xSQLServerLogin]sqlLogintestdomain\\testadmin' was found while processing the specification for node 'localhost'.
Change the name of this resource so that it is unique within the node specification.
```

This is the DSC configuration taken from the blog post and that I'm trying to apply:

```
configuration sql-primary {
    Param (
        # Get deployment details
        [Parameter(Mandatory)]
        [String]$deploymentPrefix,
        [Parameter(Mandatory)]
        [String]$DomainName,
        [String]$DomainNetbiosName = (Get-NetBIOSName -DomainName $DomainName),

        # Credentials
        [Parameter(Mandatory)]
        [System.Management.Automation.PSCredential]$Admincreds,
        [Parameter(Mandatory)]
        [System.Management.Automation.PSCredential]$SQLServiceCreds,
        [Parameter(Mandatory)]
        [System.Management.Automation.PSCredential]$WitnessAccount,

        # Listener Configuration
        [Parameter(Mandatory)]
        [String]$SqlAlwaysOnAvailabilityGroupListenerIp,

        # Minor things
        [String]$bacpacUri = "https://github.com/AvyanConsultingCorp/pci-paas-webapp-ase-sqldb-appgateway-keyvault-oms/raw/master/artifacts/ContosoPayments.bacpac",
        [UInt32]$DatabaseEnginePort = 1433,
        [UInt32]$DatabaseMirrorPort = 5022
    )

    Import-DscResource -ModuleName PSDesiredStateConfiguration, xPSDesiredStateConfiguration, xComputerManagement, xNetworking, xActiveDirectory, xFailOverCluster, xSQLServer, xDatabase, xSmbShare
    [System.Management.Automation.PSCredential]$DomainCreds = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential ("${DomainNetbiosName}\$($Admincreds.UserName)", $Admincreds.Password)
    [System.Management.Automation.PSCredential]$DomainFQDNCreds = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential ("${DomainName}\$($Admincreds.UserName)", $Admincreds.Password)
    [System.Management.Automation.PSCredential]$SQLCreds = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential ("${DomainNetbiosName}\$($SQLServiceCreds.UserName)", $SQLServiceCreds.Password)

    # Prepare for configuration
    Enable-CredSSPNTLM -DomainName $DomainName
    $features = @("Failover-Clustering", "RSAT-Clustering-Mgmt", "RSAT-Clustering-PowerShell", "RSAT-AD-PowerShell")
    $ports = @(59999, $DatabaseEnginePort, $DatabaseMirrorPort)
    WaitForSqlSetup

    Node localhost {
        LocalConfigurationManager {
            ConfigurationMode  = "ApplyOnly"
            RebootNodeIfNeeded = $true
        }

        User DisableLocalAdmin {
            Disabled = $true
            UserName = $Admincreds.UserName

            Ensure = "Present"
        }
        WindowsFeatureSet Prereqs {
            IncludeAllSubFeature = $true
            Name                 = $features

            Ensure               = "Present"
        }
        File SetupFolder {
            DestinationPath = "C:\setup"
            Type            = "Directory"

            Ensure          = "Present"
        }
        xSmbShare MySMBShare {
            Name       = "Setup"
            Path       = "C:\Setup"
            FullAccess = "Everyone"

            DependsOn  = "[File]SetupFolder"
            Ensure     = "Present"
        }
        xRemoteFile FileDownload {
            DestinationPath = "C:\setup\ContosoPayments.bacpac"
            MatchSource     = $true
            Uri             = $bacpacUri

            DependsOn       = "[File]SetupFolder"
        }
        foreach ($port in $ports) {
            xFirewall "rule-$port" {
                Access       = "Allow"
                Description  = "Inbound rule for SQL Server to allow $port TCP traffic."
                Direction    = "Inbound"
                DisplayGroup = "SQL Server"
                DisplayName  = "SQL Server $port (TCP-In)"
                Name         = "SQL-Server-$port-TCP-In"
                LocalPort    = $port -as [String]
                Protocol     = "TCP"
                State        = "Enabled"

                Ensure       = "Present"
            }
        }

        xWaitForADDomain DscForestWait { 
            DomainName           = $DomainName
            DomainUserCredential = $DomainCreds
            RetryCount           = $RetryCount
            RetryIntervalSec     = $RetryIntervalSec

            DependsOn            = "[WindowsFeatureSet]Prereqs"
        }
        xComputer DomainJoin {
            Name       = $env:COMPUTERNAME
            DomainName = $DomainName
            Credential = $DomainCreds

            DependsOn  = "[xWaitForADDomain]DscForestWait"
        }

        xSQLServerServiceAccount "sqlServiceDomainAccount" {
            SQLServer       = $env:COMPUTERNAME
            SQLInstanceName = "MSSQLSERVER"
            ServiceType     = "DatabaseEngine"
            ServiceAccount  = $SQLCreds
            RestartService  = $true
        }
        Script setSpn {
            GetScript            = "@{Ensure = `"set spn for sql service`"}"
            TestScript           = { $false }
            SetScript            = ( {
                    Invoke-Expression "setspn -D MSSQLSvc/{0}.{1}:1433 {0}$"
                    Invoke-Expression "setspn -D MSSQLSvc/{0}.{1} {0}$"
                    Invoke-Expression "setspn -S MSSQLSvc/{0}.{1}:1433 {2}"
                    Invoke-Expression "setspn -S MSSQLSvc/{0}.{1} {2}"
                } -f $env:COMPUTERNAME, $DomainName, $SQLServiceCreds.UserName )

            PsDscRunAsCredential = $DomainCreds
        }
        xCluster FailoverCluster {
            DomainAdministratorCredential = $DomainCreds
            Name                          = "${deploymentPrefix}-sql-cls"
            StaticIPAddress               = "${SqlAlwaysOnAvailabilityGroupListenerIp}0"

            PsDscRunAsCredential          = $DomainCreds
        }
        Script CloudWitness {
            SetScript            = ( {
                    Set-ClusterQuorum -CloudWitness -AccountName "{0}" -AccessKey "{1}"
                } -f $WitnessAccount.UserName, $WitnessAccount.GetNetworkCredential().Password )
            TestScript           = "(Get-ClusterQuorum).QuorumResource.Name -eq `"Cloud Witness`""
            GetScript            = "@{Ensure = if ((Get-ClusterQuorum).QuorumResource.Name -eq `"Cloud Witness`") {`"Present`"} else {`"Absent`"}}"

            DependsOn            = "[xCluster]FailoverCluster"
            PsDscRunAsCredential = $DomainCreds
        }
        foreach ($user in @($DomainCreds.UserName, $SQLCreds.UserName, "NT SERVICE\ClusSvc")) {
            xSQLServerLogin "sqlLogin$user" {
                LoginType       = "WindowsUser"
                Name            = $user
                SQLInstanceName = "MSSQLSERVER"
                SQLServer       = $env:COMPUTERNAME

                Ensure          = "Present"
            }
        }
        xSQLServerRole sqlAdmins {
            MembersToInclude = @($DomainCreds.UserName, $SQLCreds.UserName)
            ServerRoleName   = "sysadmin"
            SQLInstanceName  = "MSSQLSERVER"
            SQLServer        = $env:COMPUTERNAME

            DependsOn        = "[xComputer]DomainJoin"
            Ensure           = "Present"
        }
        foreach ($user in @("NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM", "NT SERVICE\ClusSvc")) {
            xSQLServerPermission "sqlPermission-$user" {
                InstanceName = "MSSQLSERVER"
                NodeName     = $env:COMPUTERNAME
                Permission   = @("AlterAnyAvailabilityGroup", "ViewServerState", "ConnectSQL")
                Principal    = $user

                Ensure       = "Present"
            }
        }

        xSQLServerMaxDop DegreeOfParallelism {
            DynamicAlloc    = $false
            MaxDop          = 1
            SQLServer       = $env:COMPUTERNAME
            SQLInstanceName = "MSSQLSERVER"

            Ensure          = "Present"
        }
        xSQLServerAlwaysOnService enableHadr {
            SQLServer       = $env:computername
            SQLInstanceName = "MSSQLSERVER"

            DependsOn       = "[xCluster]FailoverCluster"
            Ensure          = "Present"
        }
        xSQLServerEndpoint endpointHadr {
            EndPointName    = "${deploymentPrefix}-sql-endpoint"
            Port            = $DatabaseMirrorPort
            SQLInstanceName = "MSSQLSERVER"
            SQLServer       = $env:computername

            DependsOn       = "[xSQLServerAlwaysOnService]enableHadr"
            Ensure          = "Present"
        }
        xSQLServerEndpointPermission endpointPermission {
            InstanceName = "MSSQLSERVER"
            NodeName     = $env:computername
            Name         = "${deploymentPrefix}-sql-endpoint"
            Principal    = $SQLCreds.UserName
            Permission   = "CONNECT"

            DependsOn    = "[xSQLServerEndpoint]endpointHadr"
            Ensure       = "Present"
        }
        xSQLServerEndpointState endpointStart {
            InstanceName = "MSSQLSERVER"
            NodeName     = $env:computername
            Name         = "${deploymentPrefix}-sql-endpoint"
            State        = "Started"

            DependsOn    = "[xSQLServerEndpoint]endpointHadr"
        }

        xSQLServerAlwaysOnAvailabilityGroup AvailabilityGroup {
            AvailabilityMode     = "SynchronousCommit"
            Name                 = "${deploymentPrefix}-sql-ag"
            SQLServer            = $env:computername
            SQLInstanceName      = "MSSQLSERVER"

            DependsOn            = @("[xSQLServerEndpointState]endpointStart", "[xCluster]FailoverCluster", "[Script]setSpn")
            Ensure               = "Present"
            PsDscRunAsCredential = $SQLCreds
        }
        xSQLServerAvailabilityGroupListener AvailabilityGroupListener {
            AvailabilityGroup    = "${deploymentPrefix}-sql-ag"
            IpAddress            = "$SqlAlwaysOnAvailabilityGroupListenerIp/255.255.255.0"
            InstanceName         = "MSSQLSERVER"
            NodeName             = $env:COMPUTERNAME
            Name                 = "${deploymentPrefix}-sql-ag"
            Port                 = 59999

            DependsOn            = "[xSQLServerAlwaysOnAvailabilityGroup]AvailabilityGroup"
            Ensure               = "Present"
            PsDscRunAsCredential = $DomainCreds
        }

        xDatabase DeployBacPac {
            Credentials      = $DomainCreds
            BacPacPath       = "C:\setup\ContosoPayments.bacpac"
            DatabaseName     = "ContosoClinic"
            SqlServer        = $env:COMPUTERNAME
            SqlServerVersion = "2016-SP1"

            DependsOn        = @( "[xSQLServerAlwaysOnAvailabilityGroup]AvailabilityGroup", "[xRemoteFile]FileDownload" )
            Ensure           = "Present"
        }
        xSQLServerAlwaysOnAvailabilityGroupDatabaseMembership DatabaseToAlwaysOn {
            AvailabilityGroupName = "${deploymentPrefix}-sql-ag"
            BackupPath            = "\\${deploymentPrefix}-sql-0\setup\"
            DatabaseName          = "ContosoClinic"
            SQLServer             = $env:COMPUTERNAME
            SQLInstanceName       = "MSSQLSERVER"

            DependsOn             = @("[xDatabase]DeployBacPac", "[xSQLServerAlwaysOnAvailabilityGroup]AvailabilityGroup" )
            Ensure                = "Present"
            PsDscRunAsCredential  = $SQLCreds
        }
    }
}

configuration sql-secondary {
    Param (
        # Get deployment details
        [Parameter(Mandatory)]
        [String]$deploymentPrefix,
        [Parameter(Mandatory)]
        [String]$DomainName,
        [String]$DomainNetbiosName = (Get-NetBIOSName -DomainName $DomainName),

        # Credentials
        [Parameter(Mandatory)]
        [System.Management.Automation.PSCredential]$Admincreds,
        [Parameter(Mandatory)]
        [System.Management.Automation.PSCredential]$SQLServicecreds,

        # Minor things
        [string]$clusterIp,
        [UInt32]$DatabaseEnginePort = 1433,
        [UInt32]$DatabaseMirrorPort = 5022
    )

    Import-DscResource -ModuleName PSDesiredStateConfiguration, xComputerManagement, xNetworking, xActiveDirectory, xFailoverCluster, xSQLServer
    [System.Management.Automation.PSCredential]$DomainCreds = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential ("${DomainNetbiosName}\$($Admincreds.UserName)", $Admincreds.Password)
    [System.Management.Automation.PSCredential]$DomainFQDNCreds = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential ("${DomainName}\$($Admincreds.UserName)", $Admincreds.Password)
    [System.Management.Automation.PSCredential]$SQLCreds = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential ("${DomainNetbiosName}\$($SQLServicecreds.UserName)", $SQLServicecreds.Password)

    # Prepare for configuration
    $features = @("Failover-Clustering", "RSAT-Clustering-Mgmt", "RSAT-Clustering-PowerShell", "RSAT-AD-PowerShell")
    $ports = @(59999, $DatabaseEnginePort, $DatabaseMirrorPort)
    WaitForSqlSetup

    Node localhost {
        LocalConfigurationManager {
            ConfigurationMode  = "ApplyOnly"
            RebootNodeIfNeeded = $true
        }

        User DisableLocalAdmin {
            Disabled = $true
            UserName = $Admincreds.UserName

            Ensure = "Present"
        }
        WindowsFeatureSet Prereqs {
            Name                 = $features
            IncludeAllSubFeature = $true

            Ensure               = "Present"
        }
        foreach ($port in $ports) {
            xFirewall "rule-$port" {
                Access       = "Allow"
                Description  = "Inbound rule for SQL Server to allow $port TCP traffic."
                Direction    = "Inbound"
                DisplayName  = "SQL Server $port (TCP-In)"
                DisplayGroup = "SQL Server"
                Name         = "SQL-Server-$port-TCP-In"
                LocalPort    = $port -as [String]
                Protocol     = "TCP"
                State        = "Enabled"

                Ensure       = "Present"
            }
        }
        xWaitForADDomain DscForestWait { 
            DomainName           = $DomainName 
            DomainUserCredential = $DomainCreds
            RetryCount           = $RetryCount 
            RetryIntervalSec     = $RetryIntervalSec 

            DependsOn            = "[WindowsFeatureSet]Prereqs"
        }
        xComputer DomainJoin {
            Name       = $env:COMPUTERNAME
            DomainName = $DomainName
            Credential = $DomainCreds

            DependsOn  = "[xWaitForADDomain]DscForestWait"
        }

        xSQLServerServiceAccount "sqlServiceDomainAccount" {
            SQLServer       = $env:COMPUTERNAME
            SQLInstanceName = "MSSQLSERVER"
            ServiceType     = "DatabaseEngine"
            ServiceAccount  = $SQLCreds
            RestartService  = $true
        }
        Script setSpn {
            GetScript            = "@{Ensure = `"set spn for sql service`"}"
            TestScript           = { $false }
            SetScript            = ( {
                    Invoke-Expression "setspn -D MSSQLSvc/{0}.{1}:1433 {0}$"
                    Invoke-Expression "setspn -D MSSQLSvc/{0}.{1} {0}$"
                    Invoke-Expression "setspn -S MSSQLSvc/{0}.{1}:1433 {2}"
                    Invoke-Expression "setspn -S MSSQLSvc/{0}.{1} {2}"
                } -f $env:COMPUTERNAME, $DomainName, $SQLServiceCreds.UserName)

            PsDscRunAsCredential = $DomainCreds
        }
        foreach ($user in @($DomainCreds.UserName, $SQLCreds.UserName, "NT SERVICE\ClusSvc")) {
            xSQLServerLogin "sqlLogin$user" {
                Name            = $user
                LoginType       = "WindowsUser"
                SQLInstanceName = "MSSQLSERVER"
                SQLServer       = $env:COMPUTERNAME

                Ensure          = "Present"
            }
        }
        xSQLServerRole sqlAdmins {
            MembersToInclude = @($DomainCreds.UserName, $SQLCreds.UserName)
            ServerRoleName   = "sysadmin"
            SQLInstanceName  = "MSSQLSERVER"
            SQLServer        = $env:COMPUTERNAME

            DependsOn        = "[xComputer]DomainJoin"
            Ensure           = "Present"
        }
        foreach ($user in @("NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM", "NT SERVICE\ClusSvc")) {
            xSQLServerPermission "sqlPermission-$user" {
                InstanceName = "MSSQLSERVER"
                NodeName     = $env:COMPUTERNAME
                Permission   = @("AlterAnyAvailabilityGroup", "ViewServerState", "ConnectSQL")
                Principal    = $user

                Ensure       = "Present"
            }
        }
        xSQLServerMaxDop DegreeOfParallelism {
            DynamicAlloc    = $false
            MaxDop          = 1
            SQLServer       = $env:COMPUTERNAME
            SQLInstanceName = "MSSQLSERVER"

            Ensure          = "Present"
        }

        xWaitForCluster waitForCluster {
            Name                 = "${deploymentPrefix}-sql-cls"
            RetryIntervalSec     = $RetryIntervalSec
            RetryCount           = $RetryCount

            PsDscRunAsCredential = $DomainCreds
        }
        script joinCluster {
            GetScript            = "@{Ensure = `"join node to cluster with script resource, as cluster resource doesn't work in Azure`"}"
            TestScript           = "( Get-ClusterNode -Cluster {0} | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name ) -contains `"{1}`"" -f $clusterIp, $env:COMPUTERNAME
            SetScript            = "Add-ClusterNode -Name {0} -NoStorage -Cluster {1}" -f $env:COMPUTERNAME, $clusterIp

            DependsOn = "[xWaitForCluster]waitForCluster"
            PsDscRunAsCredential = $DomainCreds
        }

        xSQLServerAlwaysOnService enableHadr {
            SQLServer       = $env:computername
            SQLInstanceName = "MSSQLSERVER"

            DependsOn       = "[Script]joinCluster"
            Ensure          = "Present"
        }
        xSQLServerEndpoint endpointHadr {
            EndPointName    = "${deploymentPrefix}-sql-endpoint"
            Port            = $DatabaseMirrorPort
            SQLInstanceName = "MSSQLSERVER"
            SQLServer       = $env:computername

            DependsOn       = "[xSQLServerAlwaysOnService]enableHadr"
            Ensure          = "Present"
        }
        xSQLServerEndpointPermission endpointPermission {
            InstanceName = "MSSQLSERVER"
            NodeName     = $env:computername
            Name         = "${deploymentPrefix}-sql-endpoint"
            Principal    = $SQLCreds.UserName
            Permission   = "CONNECT"

            DependsOn    = "[xSQLServerEndpoint]endpointHadr"
            Ensure       = "Present"
        }
        xSQLServerEndpointState endpointStart {
            InstanceName = "MSSQLSERVER"
            NodeName     = $env:computername
            Name         = "${deploymentPrefix}-sql-endpoint"
            State        = "Started"

            DependsOn    = "[xSQLServerEndpoint]endpointHadr"
        }


        xWaitForAvailabilityGroup waitforAG {
            Name                 = "${deploymentPrefix}-sql-ag"
            RetryIntervalSec     = $RetryIntervalSec
            RetryCount           = $RetryCount

            DependsOn            = @("[xSQLServerEndpointState]endpointStart", "[Script]joinCluster", "[Script]setSpn")
            PsDscRunAsCredential = $DomainCreds
        }
        xSQLServerAlwaysOnAvailabilityGroupReplica AddReplica {
            AvailabilityGroupName         = "${deploymentPrefix}-sql-ag"
            AvailabilityMode              = "SynchronousCommit"
            Name                          = $env:COMPUTERNAME
            PrimaryReplicaSQLServer       = "${deploymentPrefix}-sql-0"
            PrimaryReplicaSQLInstanceName = "MSSQLSERVER"
            SQLInstanceName               = "MSSQLSERVER"
            SQLServer                     = $env:COMPUTERNAME

            DependsOn                     = "[xWaitForAvailabilityGroup]waitforAG"
            Ensure                        = "Present"
            PsDscRunAsCredential          = $SQLCreds
        }
    }
}

function WaitForSqlSetup {
    while ($true) {
        try {
            Get-ScheduledTaskInfo "\ConfigureSqlImageTasks\RunConfigureImage" -ErrorAction Stop
            Start-Sleep -Seconds 5
        }
        catch {
            break
        }
    }
}

function Get-NetBIOSName { 
    [OutputType([string])]
    param(
        [string]$DomainName
    )

    if ($DomainName.Contains(".")) {
        $length = $DomainName.IndexOf(".")
        if ( $length -ge 16) {
            $length = 15
        }
        return $DomainName.Substring(0, $length)
    }
    else {
        if ($DomainName.Length -gt 15) {
            return $DomainName.Substring(0, 15)
        }
        else {
            return $DomainName
        }
    }
}

function Enable-CredSSPNTLM { 
    param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
        [string]$DomainName
    )

    # This is needed for the case where NTLM authentication is used

    Write-Verbose "STARTED:Setting up CredSSP for NTLM"

    Enable-WSManCredSSP -Role client -DelegateComputer localhost, *.$DomainName -Force -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
    Enable-WSManCredSSP -Role server -Force -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

    if (-not (Test-Path HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\CredentialsDelegation -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue)) {
        New-Item -Path HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows -Name "\CredentialsDelegation" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
    }

    if ( -not (Get-ItemProperty HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\CredentialsDelegation -Name "AllowFreshCredentialsWhenNTLMOnly" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue)) {
        New-ItemProperty HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\CredentialsDelegation -Name "AllowFreshCredentialsWhenNTLMOnly" -value "1" -PropertyType dword -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
    }

    if (-not (Get-ItemProperty HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\CredentialsDelegation -Name "ConcatenateDefaults_AllowFreshNTLMOnly" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue)) {
        New-ItemProperty HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\CredentialsDelegation -Name "ConcatenateDefaults_AllowFreshNTLMOnly" -value "1" -PropertyType dword -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
    }

    if (-not (Test-Path HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\CredentialsDelegation\AllowFreshCredentialsWhenNTLMOnly -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue)) {
        New-Item -Path HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\CredentialsDelegation -Name "AllowFreshCredentialsWhenNTLMOnly" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
    }

    if (-not (Get-ItemProperty HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\CredentialsDelegation\AllowFreshCredentialsWhenNTLMOnly -Name "1" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue)) {
        New-ItemProperty HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\CredentialsDelegation\AllowFreshCredentialsWhenNTLMOnly -Name "1" -value "wsman/$env:COMPUTERNAME" -PropertyType string -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
    }

    if (-not (Get-ItemProperty HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\CredentialsDelegation\AllowFreshCredentialsWhenNTLMOnly -Name "2" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue)) {
        New-ItemProperty HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\CredentialsDelegation\AllowFreshCredentialsWhenNTLMOnly -Name "2" -value "wsman/localhost" -PropertyType string -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
    }

    if (-not (Get-ItemProperty HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\CredentialsDelegation\AllowFreshCredentialsWhenNTLMOnly -Name "3" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue)) {
        New-ItemProperty HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\CredentialsDelegation\AllowFreshCredentialsWhenNTLMOnly -Name "3" -value "wsman/*.$DomainName" -PropertyType string -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
    }

    Write-Verbose "DONE:Setting up CredSSP for NTLM"
}

[Int]$RetryCount = 100
[Int]$RetryIntervalSec = 15

# $cd = @{
#     AllNodes = @(
#         @{
#             NodeName                    = "localhost"
#             PSDscAllowDomainUser        = $true
#             PSDscAllowPlainTextPassword = $true
#         }
#     )
# }
```

And this is the exact ARM Template I'm deploying
https://pastebin.com/d52BpEFM

Comment: also, feel free to get the latest version of dsc, with slightly different order of steps. i find it to be more stable, as with the version you are using, sometimes secondary node doesnt get added to the sql alwayson in time and the db doesnt get synced to that node.

Comment: also, you wouldn't believe how much effort i've put into debugging that configuration ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just to sum up a bunch of points here:

1. domain and sql accounts should be different
2. sql cluster ip address should be in one of the cluster networks
3. you need to precreate the dns name record for the load balancer (due to how i'm doing everything in parallel i've decided to put that functionallity into the domain provisioning dsc configurations)
4. to check deployment you can use [always on dashboard](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/availability-groups/windows/use-the-always-on-dashboard-sql-server-management-studio)

> Cannot find path 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\PowerShell\3\DSC'
> because it does not exist.

Seems to be a general error being thrown when something goes wrong (at least I could never find a pattern why it appeared), so its safe to disregard that error, it will be gone when you fix the real error (in my experience).

<strike>SQL provisioning fails (sometimes) with weird errors (usually dns\timing related). I'm not sure how this would behave in an environment where domain is precreated in advance. it might be less fragile overall.</strike> In my latest commit (at the time of writing) I believe I've addressed some of the stability issues, and I'm quite sure with domain, storage for backups, keyvault precreated those issues shouldn't be present at all.

Comment: Never had problems you mentioned with the previous version of the template.